# How to add a mouselistener to a vertex - jgraphx

Tags: java, jgrapht, jgraphx, jgraph

How can I add a mouselistener to a specific vertex in jgraphx?

```
graphComponent.getGraphControl().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e1) {
```

I can use this fro graphcomponent but how can I specify it for a vertex?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the graphcomponent class's `getCellAt(int x, int y)` method with the MouseEvent class's `getX()` and `getY()` methods. This will return you an object if there is a vertex (or edge) where you clicked, then with a simple comparison you can decide which vertex is it.

Here is an example:

```
graphComponent.getGraphControl().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
{
@Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
    {    
        mxCell cell =(mxCell) getGraphComponent().getCellAt(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if(cell != null && cell.equals(YOUR_VERTEX))
        {
            //specific thing you want to do on click
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `mxCellHandler` for a given cell `state`, i.e. your specific vertex. You could check the `createHandler()` of the `mxGraphComponent` class.

Hope this helps.